# how to change text format date to date format in excel?

Tags: r, excel

my data has date in below format I have to clean it and make it as correct date format. Tried format cell didnt work, used R didnt work

| Date | Correct date |
| --- | --- |
| Dec 26, 2012 | 26-12-2012 |
| Jan 2, 2012 |  |
| Jan 16, 2012 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `format` - `%b %d, %Y` to convert to `Date` class and then reconvert  to another format `%d-%m-%Y` (as it is different from the default format used in `Date` class - `%Y-%m-%d`) which would be a `character` class

```
df1$Correctdate <- format(as.Date(df1$Date, '%b %d, %Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

-output

```
df1
#          Date Correctdate
#1 Dec 26, 2012  26-12-2012
#2  Jan 2, 2012  02-01-2012
#3 Jan 16, 2012  16-01-2012
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = c("Dec 26, 2012", "Jan 2, 2012", "Jan 16, 2012"))
```